# Must I implement Applicative and Functor to implement a Monad

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, applicative, fam-proposal

I'm trying to implement a Monad instance. As a simpler example, assume the following:

```
data Maybee a = Notheeng | Juust a 

instance Monad Maybee where
   return x = Juust x
   Notheeng >>= f = Notheeng
   Juust x >>= f = f x
   fail _ = Notheeng
```

This should be the standard implementation of Maybe as far as I know. However, this doesn't compile, because the compiler complains:

> No instance for (Applicative Maybee)

and similarly he wants a Functor instance once the Applicative is given.

So: Simple question: Must I always implement Functor and Applicative before I can implement a Monad?

Comment: I anticipate a lot of questions about this, in the wake of GHC 7.10's release. Should we create a *Functor-Applicative-Monad proposal* tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GHC 7.10 and above, you must implement `Functor` and `Applicative`. The class definitions for `Monad` mandate the superclass instances:

```
class Functor f => Applicative f where ...
class Applicative m => Monad m where ...
```

Note that once you have a `Monad` instance, the `Functor` and `Applicative` instances can be defined generically with no additional effort:

```
import Control.Monad

-- suppose we defined a Monad instance:
instance Monad m where ...

instance Functor m where
    fmap = liftM

instance Applicative m where
    pure = return
    (<*>) = ap
```

Comment: Actually not true: In 7.8 and older, `Monad` had no superclass constraint whatsoever.

Comment: Duh, that's quite a heavy mistake from me.

Comment: It's not a great idea to implement `pure = return`, I don't think. It's possible `return` will eventually go away, and IIRC there's even a warning available to discover when `return` is implemented as anything but `pure`.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it wasn't the case before, it's a change that was introduced in ghc7.10 under the name of [Functor-Applicative-Monad Proposal](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal).

Answer (score 8):

It is compulsory to define instances for `Functor` and `Applicative` (the second one is a new requirement in newer versions of Haskell), but it's actually no big deal because if you don't want to hand-write your own instances you can just use these ones:

```
import Control.Applicative (Applicative(..))
import Control.Monad       (liftM, ap)

-- Monad m

instance Functor m where
    fmap = liftM

instance Applicative m where
    pure  = return
    (<*>) = ap
```